# How to ms access query to show sums for all account types even if they are 0?

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

I have 2 tables: Commitments Table & Account Types Table.

When a commitment record is added, it is associated with an account_ID from the Account table.
I have a query that puts it all together and then gets reflected in a form that shows the totals of all commitments BY account_ID.

How do I make sure that even if there are no commitment records for a certain account_ID, it still shows up in the query & report, but with sum being $0?

Answer (score 0):

LEFT JOIN gives the rows that (INNER) JOIN does plus unmatched left rows extended by NULLs. The accounts with no commitments are the ones whose account_IDs don't appear in your current summary:

```
select * from account_totals
union
select a.account_ID, 0 as total
from Accounts a
left join account_total t
on a.account_ID = t.account_ID
where t.total IS NULL
```

You can probably easily introduce an appropriate LEFT join into your current query instead:

```
select a.account_ID, count(c.commitment_ID) as total
from Accounts a
left join Commitments c
on a.account_ID = c.account_ID
group by a.account_ID
```

COUNT of non-* returns the number of non-NULL rows. For unmatched-account_ID rows added by the LEFT JOIN the commitment_ID is null and in a group of its own and the [count is 0](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-GB/article/GROUP-BY-Clause-84eeb766-25d2-4aa1-8eea-002bb65ef3a0).